# Are questions about installing astronomy-related python packages on topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

In particular, PyRAF is a tool for analyzing spectra. Aside from [its documentation](http://stsdas.stsci.edu/pyraf.new/doc/pyraf_tutorial/Unimplemented.html) there are few online resources about it, and no question and answer sites for it. Can the Astronomy Stack Exchange fill that gap?

The proposed question: After installing PyRAF with 
        `$pip install stsci.distutils` and
        `$pip install stscipython`

I try to run it with `$pyraf` or, in python, `>>> import pyraf`. Both actions give a `segmentation fault: 11`

How can I install the software so that it will run properly?

Answer (score 5):

I see no reason that such a question couldn't be asked here since our relevant topics include:

> Setting up, using and maintaining your astronomy related equipment

Software could be viewed in a sense as virtual equipment.

Of course, if the software package were not astronomy specific it would not be on topic. There is the risk that the answer to the question is not specific to that particular software package, but I don't think that is a good reason to deem the question irrelevant.